# Bootstrap: Mobile specific changes how?

Tags: css

I have a large button and i need to change its degree of margin and padding when viewing the page on mobile phones.

Whatis the best way of doing this please?

basically i need:

```
  .cta-btn{
   margin: 70px 0;
  }
```

to become:

```
  .cta-btn{
   margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

when the visitor is on a mobile or other small screened device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bootstrap, there are specific helpers just for that: [Bootstrap media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

Anyway, this is wat you could do:

```
.cta-btn{
  margin: 70px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .cta-btn{
   margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
```